# Modifying div with updated results from inner elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

So this is what I'm trying to do here:

My project is basically an e-commerce website. I am using a global "Store" object that has two properties that are objects, "cart" and "stock". On the front page, I have grid of images to represent the store's stock with the buttons that show up as you hover over them that says, "Add" and "Remove". Each time you hit "Add", the both object property changes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Amazing Stuff for CHEAP
    </title>
    <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <img id="logo" src="images/hello.png">
        <img id="banner" src="images/welcome.jpeg">
        <button id="btn-show-cart">Show Cart</button>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li class="menuItem">All items</li>
            <li class="menuItem">Books</li>
            <li class="menuItem">Clothing</li>
            <li class="menuItem">Tech</li>
            <li class="menuItem">Gifts</li>
            <li class="menuItem">Stationary</li>
            <li class="menuItem">Supplies</li>
        </ul>
        <div id="productView">
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        jeffreyzhuu@globalwealth.com
    </div>
    <div id="modal" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <div id="modal-content">
        </div>
        <button id="btn-hide-cart">X
        </button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to create a shopping cart by adding div's with class name "product" to a main div with id "cart" which is created dynamically with a click of a button. The output of the cart would look something like this:

```
<div id="cart>
   <div class="product>
      <p>10</p>
      <button class="btn-add">+</button>   
   </div>
</div>
```

For each product in the cart, there are two buttons which updates the cart which the same functionality as described above the code. The cart can be shown by hitting a button, "Show Cart" and closed with the button "X". These work fine. The issue is the rerendering of the cart container itself. The cart would eventually be displayed as a modal.

```
    function renderCart(container, storeInstance) {
        // console.log('before render:');
        // console.log(container);


        var newContainer = document.createElement("div");
        newContainer.id = container.id;

        for (var item in storeInstance.cart) {
            var currentItem = document.createElement("div");
            currentItem.id = item;

            var label = document.createElement("p");
            var labelNode = document.createTextNode(item);
            label.appendChild(labelNode);


            var quantity = document.createElement("p");
            var quantityNode = document.createTextNode("" + storeInstance.cart[item]);
            quantity.appendChild(quantityNode);
            quantity.classList.add("quantity");


            // Event listener is on productList......
            var addBtn = document.createElement("button");
            addBtn.classList.add("btn-add");
            addBtn.innerHTML = "+";


            var removeBtn = document.createElement("button");
            removeBtn.classList.add("btn-remove");
            removeBtn.innerHTML = "-";


            var totalCost = document.createElement("p");
            var totalCostNode = document.createTextNode("$" + storeInstance.cart[item] * storeInstance.stock[item].price + ".00");
            totalCost.appendChild(totalCostNode);

            currentItem.appendChild(label);
            currentItem.appendChild(quantity);
            currentItem.appendChild(addBtn);
            currentItem.appendChild(removeBtn);
            currentItem.appendChild(totalCost);

            newContainer.appendChild(currentItem);
            console.log(newContainer);
        }
}
```

To clarify code above:

I've created a div to represent the modal and modal content, the container in the above argument is appended to the modal content

Here are some things I've tried:

creating a document fragment and append each product to that and use the method replaceChild, which did not work

creating a completely new div and replacing the current one, this is the method I'm almost certain would work, but I'm not too sure why it does not.

Basically, I want the cart to be updated each time I add or remove an item from my cart and have the Store's updated properties displayed on the modal when "Show Cart" is clicked and have the modal display updated information if the modal Add/Remove buttons are clicked.

I am looking for a pure javascript approach i.e. no jQuery

Comment: Where is the click event for btn-add?

Comment: @Spangle I have a function that creates a product view which is the grid layout I mentioned above. The click events are both triggered at the product view. I have used the same ID for both the product (which goes inside product view, which i know is bad... But i couldn't figure out a way such that I could use event propagation properly) The buttons work fine, but I'm not able to replace the cart div.

Comment: Yeah, do not use the same id. What do you click on to add the items to the cart?  So the cart is an array of objects right and you render it by looping through the objects, and for each, create the cart item? Is that html snippet above the cart and is there only one of those? If so, why is there the add button in it? Just having a hard time visualising what you are doing sorry. Are you just wanting to have a list of items, and when you click on one, it is added to a cart div?

Comment: @Spangle Thank you for your help. Turns out having the same id is what caused my issue. In the product div and modal-content div id's (since they have the same) with classes and it fixed the issue. I didn't think that was the cause, but I guess it was. :)

Comment: Good job working it out :)